# How to arrange my social media icons vertically?

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to arrange my social media icons vertically at the top right corner of my website. I tried adding clear both, but it doesn't seem to work. Please have a look at my HtML and CSS code.

HTML code:

```
<div id="cover">
<div class="mediaicon">
  <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/prashant.bagga1" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/prashant774/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/splendidprash" class="fa fa-snapchat"></a>
  </li>
  </ul> 
</div> 
<div class="cover-content">
  <h1>Being A Technocrat</h1>
  <h2>Prashant Bagga</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.mediaicon {
 padding: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-top: 100px;
 }

 .mediaicon li {
 clear: both!important;
 }

 .fa {
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 }

.fa:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.fa-facebook {
background: #3B5998;
color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
background: #007bb5;
color: white;
}
.fa-snapchat {
background: #fffc00;
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
#cover {
background: url("http://moheban-ahlebeit.com/images/Texture-Wallpaper/Texture-Wallpaper-2.jpg") no-repeat center bottom;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 800px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.cover-content {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 100px;
width: 100%;
height: 800px;
}

h1 {
color: #FFF;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-size: 600%;
line-height: 60px;
padding-top: 0;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
color:#FFF;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to create a MCVE ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You just need to position them somehow. `float: right` might be what you're looking for? there are a bunch of ways to make something go to the right. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWyKPq

Comment: Could you just use "display: block" to achieve what you want in terms of stacking them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you want the text centered on the viewport.
I would actually recommend making 2 columns for this, one for the text, and one for the icons.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="social-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/prashant.bagga1" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/prashant774/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/splendidprash" class="fa fa-snapchat"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cover-content">
    <h1>Being A Technocrat</h1>
    <h2>Prashant Bagga</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changed CSS

```
.social-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
.social-menu ul li {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: url("http://moheban-ahlebeit.com/images/Texture-Wallpaper/Texture-Wallpaper-2.jpg") no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLnkvo2z/1/

Comment: Thank you Sean, but now my icons are not vertical.

Comment: Forgot to link the fiddle.  It works, unless I'm misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: You can see in the image of the question above. I just want that horizontal row of icons to be vertical. The position is correct (top right corner).

Comment: Are they not vertical in the fiddle?

Comment: Ohh yeah..right. Thats what I want. Its just that the cover content class moves a little bit up due to this code. I

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you'd like with how you want to design it.  With flex, you can make the cover content centered on the viewport, but that really is a matter of what you want to do.  https://jsfiddle.net/fLnkvo2z/3/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal way to achieve this: (**Before edit**)

Just add `float: right` and a pseudo element:`.mediaicon::after` with property `clear: both`

```
.mediaicon {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

.medication::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

**Edit:**

Changed both the top `nav` and the `media icons` to flexbox with different `justify-content` (`center` and `flex-end`)

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lkjk9r/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir..!

Comment: my headings are shifted to top left corner due to this code. Can you please help me change it ?

Comment: Did you want them to be centered? because if so, you can just add `text-align: center` to the `cover-content` class.

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit the question with an image of the wanted result (even something basic as Ms Paint)

Comment: Yeah you added some more `CSS`, but I still don't know how you want the layout to be. That's why I asked for an image

Comment: I added the image of my first page. I now want them to be vertically aligned at top right.

Answer (score 0):

Check your grid system. If you are using bootstrap then make grid system of your web page. 
I suggest you to dnt go for margin. Use Bootstrap Instead.

Comment: Sir, I am still learning how to make a website. I dont know Bootstrap, but I will make sure to use it. Thanks a lot tho..!